# Code stops running halfway in CoffeeDregs

Tags: java

I'm running some lines of codes in CoffeeDregs to see if  the code works, and although DrJava compiles the code fine, it suddenly stops running in Dregs at the line 'Room room = rooms[i]'. Could anyone tell me why this is happening, and how I can try to fix it?

If I try to RUN the code in DrJava I do get an error; java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Hotel.checkIn(Hotel.java:24)

But I don't know if this is due to it being meant to be run in Dregs or an actual error causing this.

My code is as follows;

```
class Hotel{
Room[] rooms;


Hotel() {

rooms = new Room[10];
Guest rob = new Guest("Rob");
Guest jing = new Guest("Jing");
Guest kevin = new Guest ("Kevin");

checkIn(rob);
checkIn(kevin);
checkIn(jing);

}

void checkIn(Guest guest){
 System.out.println(rooms.length);
 for (int i=1; i<rooms.length; i++){
   Room room = rooms[i];
     room.setGuest(guest);
     return;
   }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new Hotel();
 }
}


class Guest{
String guestName;

Guest(String n) {
this.guestName = n; 
}

}


class Room{
Guest guest = null;

public Guest getGuest(){
return guest;
}
  public void setGuest( Guest guest){
this.guest = guest;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the error or warnings of stack trace to better assist.

Comment: Hi, I did edit in the error I recieve when running in DrJava. I do not know what you mean by stack trace, sorry.

Comment: Hey Rob, it has nothing to do with CoffeeDregs. It has to do with the rooms list. You've written rooms = new Room[10];, which doesn't actually make any rooms, it just frees up some space for 10 rooms. The rooms aren't there yet. So when you access room[i] you get an error because no room exists. I can help you with this, but I need to know what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to check in all 3 guests into all 10 rooms. Is that correct? If you need some serious help for a deadline, leave your contact info in your profile. I'm Dutch.

Comment: Hi Henk. It's not as much for a deadline as it is me practicing for my exam of next week. I'm Dutch as well, would love to have some help with this. I'll put my skype in my profile so we can have a chat, if you still want. Thanks for the help already given!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to actually create the rooms still. Did via

```
for (int i=0; i<rooms.length;i++){
rooms[i] = new Room();
}
```